# Why I don't get the same result using the best params of the GridSearchCV in cross_val_score as GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I've used the same seed number for train-test splitting, Golorot uniform initialization, dropout, etc., but the results are still different. The GridSearchCV's result is MSE=14, while trying with both cross_val_score and manually doing Cross Validation using kfold.split(..) both had the result  MSE=16.4. What's the problem? What are other seeds I can control to get same results?

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(2)
 
kfold = KFold(3, shuffle=True,random_state=42)
 
def buildModel(layers,dropout,l2,lr):
 
    model = Sequential()
    for i, nodes in enumerate(layers):
        if i==0: 
            model.add(Dense(nodes, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='tanh',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2)))
            model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        else:
            model.add(Dense(nodes,activation='tanh',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2)))
            model.add(Dropout(dropout))
 
                
    model.add(Dense(1))
    
    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=lr,momentum=0.6),loss='mse',metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    
    return model
 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
 
 
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=buildModel)
 
parameters = {'dropout':[0.1],
              'l2':[0.1],
              'lr':[0.001,0.01,0.1],
                'layers': [[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]],
                'batch_size': [10,15,18,20,22,25],
                  'epochs':[40,45,50,55,60,65,70]}
 
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,param_grid=parameters,cv=kfold,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',verbose=10)   #r2 score
 
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train,y_train,verbose=10)
 
 
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_score = grid_search.best_score_
print(best_score)
print(best_parameters)


Best params >> 'batch_size': 20, 'dropout': 0.1, 'epochs': 65, 'l2': 0.1, 'layers': [4], 'lr': 0.1}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(2)
kfold = KFold(3, shuffle=True,random_state=42)
def buildModel():
 
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Dense(4,activation='tanh',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
            
    model.add(Dense(1))
    
    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.1,momentum=0.6),loss='mse',metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    
    return model
 
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=buildModel,epochs=65, batch_size=20)
 
results = np.average(cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'))
print(results)
```

Comment: Initial weights of all the layers still seem random to me. I don't see where you initialise weight using Glorot uniform. And biases also need to be initialised in a consistent manner. Also don't see that happening.

Comment: Thank you so much! It got solved! :)

I manually added the seed for the Dropout,     model.add(Dropout(0.1,seed=42))  and for the Glorot uniform initialization.

 

  model.add(Dense(4,activation='tanh',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1),kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1,seed=42))     
    model.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))
    
    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.01),loss='mse',metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    


Hopefully, I got the same result :).